# AWS CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. The headers are present

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have been battling with these dreaded CORS issues with AWS for a while now. I thought I had it sorted out and then it turned up again... I have done exactly want I have in the other Lambda functions that work fine.

Why won't it work now?

I have added in the headers in the response to all of the Lambda functions in my handler.js file (I am using serverless to deploy to AWS)

```
docClient.get(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            const response = {
                statusCode: 500,
                headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Required for CORS support to work
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    message: 'Failed to fetch service request from the database.',
                    error: err
                }),
            };
            callback(null, response);
        }
        else {


            const response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Required for CORS support to work
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
                }
            };
            callback(null, response);
        }
    });
```

And in the .yml file:

```
  myLambdaFunc:
    handler: handler.myLambdaFunc
    events:
      - http:
          path: myLambdaFunc
          method: POST
          cors: true
```

Comment: When this happen you need to make sure to check the HTTP status code of the response. If it’s a 4xx or 5xx error, then it’s likely not going to have an Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header — because typically when you configure a server to add that, it’s only going to get added to 2xx success responses. The browser still sees that response, though. So the reason it also logs a CORS error is to tell you that the browser received a response but it can’t expose that response to your frontend code because it lacks the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem lies with the docClient.get. I was testing with data where the primary key item being searched for was not in the table.

I wish it didn't tell me that it was a CORS issue because it really wasn't..